# Working on incoming emails with SSIS

Tags: ssis, soa, email, eai

We are quite successful in using `SSIS` for sending out email notifications. On the other hand, we are missing an Email Source Adapter.

Assume the following situation: we receive mail with standardized Attachments. (e.g. Excel) We would like to have `SSIS` run over the `(POP or IMAP)` mailbox and analyze emails and attachments.

Has anybody seen such an adaptor? No matter if commercial or open source.

Comment: do u mean to read attachment from an outlook mailbox and push the data into database ?

Comment: We have multiple requirements for several projects. 

One is we need to check a mailbox for incoming mails. detach an attachment and process the content of the attachment (e.g. a `CSV` or `XLS`). We do not want to store the attachment (e.g. like a `JPG`) in the database but the content in a semantic sensible way.

E.g. a vendor sends us data for billing in a `CVS`. We then want to check the sender, save the attachment and start a process on the billing data in the CSV.